# App runs on iOS7 simulator, but changing simulator to iOS8 it doesn't recognize CoreData store

Tags: ios7, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6, nscalendar

I have an iPad app, XCode 6, iOS 7, Storyboards and ARC.  If I change the target to 7.x, the app works fine on the simulator running 7.0.

However, if I change the simulator to 8.0, the app doesn't recognize the CoreData store created when running under 7.x (the store is still there, just not found when running on the 8.0 simulator.)  Also, none of the objects (UIButtons, UITextboxes, etc) show up either!

I don't have iOS 8 installed on my iPad (afraid stuff like this will affect my users), but the question is: just because something doesn't run on the simulator v8.0, does that mean that setting the lowest target to iOS 7, it won't run on the device if it is running iOS 8?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  Are you creating a CoreData store on iOS 7 and then packaging it in your app and installing it to iOS 8?  There is no currently supported way of copying data from a 7.x sim device to an 8.x sim device, so you need to explain what you're doing.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia you're kidding, right?  Is this only for the simulator or device as well?

Comment: No, I'm not kidding.  Please elaborate on what you are doing.  I think there is a communication issue here.  How are you getting the CoreData store from the iOS 7 sim device into the iOS 8 sim device?

Comment: Ahhh... the CoreData store (managed by MagicalRecord) is stored as normally is; I am doing nothing to move the data, because I have made no changes to it.  I would assume that the simulator would find the store when I go through CoreData initialization of the default context.  I've never had this issue before when upgrading XCode versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS 7 simulator is on a separate (virtual) machine from the iOS 8 simulator. So any data you created one of these machines, will not be found on the other.